# Firefox extension: show iframe by url

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want write a extension for firefox, i wrote a html page with iframe, like as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 300px;" id="wrapper">
        <iframe src="http://example.com" style="height:200px;width:300px"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works for me, but i want change iframe url by currnet url, when user click on extension icon, get current url, and change iframe source or delete old iframe and inner new iframe, with new url, like `http://example.com/google.com`

How can i create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when user click on extension icon

Do you mean the `browserAction` Icon or `PageAction` icon?
There is a difference.
There is also a difference if the popup is set in `manifest.json` (automatic) or via an event listener.

Sample HTML based on your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 200px; width: 300px;" id="wrapper">
      <iframe src="" style="height:200px;width:300px"></iframe>
  </div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of `popup.js`

```
// run the function
setIframe();

async function setIframe() {

  // get the active tab
  const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});

  // make the URL based on url of the tab i.e. tabs[0].url
  const url = ...... // do whatever

  // set iframe to that url 
  document.querySelector('iframe').src = url;
}
```